# Why does my footer go all the way down?

Tags: css, footer

The site is here:

http://www.cottonbrewing.com/members

It's fine if the content doesn't require the page the scroll.

CSS:

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    clear:both;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Edit 1: I must also make sure the footer is at the absolute bottom if the content is small, such as you see here: http://www.cottonbrewing.com/  that the footer is at the bottom.

Comment: Whenever I need something like that, I head for http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ -- it seems to be kept up to date with new techniques and browser support, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;`

**ADDITION**

In response to the comment, follow these guidelines for a "sticky footer":

Body

```
body
{
  height:100%;
}
```

Your container `div`:

```
#container
{
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Your footer `div`:

```
#footer
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px; /* can be changed, along with padding */
}
```

Comment: Yes that works for when the content is pass the normal browser height, but I want it to at the bottom when content is small. Like this:  http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: You want a sticky footer. That should have been stated in your question. I added to my answer.

Comment: The body height should be 100%.

Comment: Thank you evan, that helps. Still, I am left with the exact same issue I started out with.

Comment: You are floating your leftside and rightside divs. This means you can't have a sticky footer because it ignores elements that do not block the DOM.

Comment: I wrapped the floating div's in their own "#content" div that had `overflow:hidden` and it seem to work. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete **bottom:0;** and change the position to relative.